# No live output from containers running on Docker Desktop with WSL2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, console, desktop, live

I'm developing an python-django app running in docker containers (django, celery, postgres, redist...etc). It runs on Windows 10 with WSL2-Debian & Docker Desktop.

During my work I need to observe the consoles of all those containers, so I can monitor apps behavior, like when you run `docker-compose up` so you got all of them live.

When you click on the container within windowed Docker Desktop app you can see the container's console output, but not actual - it looks like it works until some point of time and there are no updates of the consoles output.
I remember it was working live just prior to a two or three Docker Desktop updates, and I'm sure it was real time there, but not now.

Did I change a setting or Docker Desktop was bugged?

PS. When I start my containers with `docker-compose up` (without -d) I can observe live logs on my shell console, but not in Docker Desktop anymore.

Any help how to restore Docker Desktop live console view?

Comment: There is an issue on GitHub about this. It must be an actual bug: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11251

Comment: I confirm that downgrade to Docker Desktop v3.3.1 resolved this issue.

Comment: There is a Docker Desktop snapshot available for you to test if the issue is resolved; see [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67916084/6309)

Comment: Docker Desktop 3.6.0 is supposed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Docker Desktop 3.4](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#upgrades) (released June 9th, yesterday) is supposed to have resolved [`docker/for-win` issue 11251](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11251).

I don't see the error after upgrading (with the normal `docker-compose`, not the beta `docker-compose` v2).

However, as commented by [the OP twk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66392/twk) and in [issue 11251](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11251#issuecomment-858386817):

> the live log is somehow broken - extra newline is added after every new line, but historical log entries (Eg. when you switch to/from another container) are displayed without newlines between entries (which is OK).

---

[Update June 29th](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11251#issuecomment-871428343) from [Mathieu Champlon](https://github.com/mat007)

> Sorry it took a while but we now have an internal build that should fix it, if you wanted to give it a try:
> [`win/stable/amd64/66242/Docker Desktop Installer.exe`](https://desktop-stage.docker.com/win/stable/amd64/66242/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe)

---

Update Aug. 2021: [Issue 11251 just closed](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11251#issuecomment-896991532) with:

> [Docker Desktop 3.6.0](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-360) has been released containing a fix for this issue.

Comment: There is still a little problem: live logs are separated by newline, but generally works.

Comment: @twk Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Docker Desktop v3.3.3

GitHub issue: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11251  as pointed by @Drarig29

Comment: Acutally, it's not working in Docker Desktop v3.3.2 as well.